# React Native Android app failed to boot up : can't find variable

Tags: android, react-native

I don't modify any part of app; I just exec following cmds on macOS:

```
react-native init ***
cd ***
react-native run-android
```

I tested on both emulator and Samsung Galaxy note 3 both are the same.
also tried adb reverse.

My $PATH is

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mohammad/Documents/sdk/platform-tools/:/Users/mohammad/Documents/sdk
```

Then I get these errors in app (as in image):

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require (http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:15)

Try the following to fix the issue:
• Ensure that the packager server is running
• Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices
• Ensure Airplane Mode is disabled
• If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device
• If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server - e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081


loadScript
    JSBundleLoader.java:66
runJSBundle
    CatalystInstanceImpl.java:177
call
    XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:906
call
    XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:899
run
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:74
handleCallback
    Handler.java:739
dispatchMessage
    Handler.java:95
dispatchMessage
    MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31
loop
    Looper.java:135
run
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196
run
    Thread.java:818
```

[image: My error in rn]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is cannot connect `the packager server of react native` and `device (or) simulator`.

To solve this problem, need to connect `the packager server` and `device (or) simulator`.

`react native` is default use `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` to connect `the packager server` and `device (or) simulator`.There has a some problem in under android 5.0 because `adb reverse` is not support under android 5.0. However, `react native` is also support with using same wi-fi network.

#### To Solve

- #### android 5.0 (or) Above

  - Need to check `the packager server` is running or not. ( Some `OS` not run automatically like `ubuntu`, but  you can run `react-native start` in your project directory. )
  - Need to connect `device (or) simulator`. ( If your using devices, need to connect your device and computer, and sure to open USB debugging mode. If your using simulator, sure to open simulator. ), ( You can check is step complete or not using `adb devices` command )
  - Run again `react-native run-android` (or) open `dev menu of react native` and press `Reload`.
- #### below android 5.0

  - Need to check `the packager server` is running or not. ( Some `OS` not run automatically like `ubuntu`, but  you can run `react-native start` in your project directory. )
  - Need to connect your device and computer on same `wi-fi network`. And add `packager server IP` on your device's `dev menu > Dev Settings > Debug server host & port for device` like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port`)
  - Run again `react-native run-android` (or) open `dev menu of react native` and press `Reload`.

---

#### Open Dev Menu

- #### Devices

  Press Menu button (or) shake device.
- #### Simulator

  Press `Ctrl + M` (or) `Cmd + M`.

---

#### Find Packager Server Host

- Computer's IP. ( On `unix` use `ifconfig` in terminal (or) On `Window` use `ipconfig`. )
- Port ( Can find on `Packager Server Terminal` like **`localhost:8081`** )

Comment: Thx for answer but I did these with no luck

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean